# Manwha where a girl is reborn and knows she's supposed to die of an illness in five years

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I'm pretty sure it's a manhwa. The female lead has pink hair. She was either reborn into the world or went back in time, but she knows she's supposed to die in like five years, however there's a cure for her illness; she has to eat a certain berry everyday for five years, but has to do it in secret so her fiance and father-in-law, who both have black hair and red eyes. I want to say she and her fiance were like 13-ish. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure this is ***[I Became the Daughter-in-Law of the Villain Because I'm Terminally Ill!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/g8e5p29/my-time-was-limited-so-i-became-the-villain-s-daughter-in-law)***.

Review by [ystrike1](https://ystrike1.tumblr.com/post/679657477667684352/i-became-the-daughter-in-law-of-the-villain?is_related_post=1):

> **Laria Rostree is a cute girl with an incurable illness that makes her cough up blood every day. She won't make it past the age of twenty. She knows this.** Her parents died in an accident and the future of the Rostree family is in shambles. She knows a few things because she had a vision. **Her illness can be cured if she eats a special rare fruit every day. That fruit can be found in Duke Icard's garden.** Duke Icard's wife was friendly with her mother. **The Duke isn't a friendly person, but he offers to take her in after her parents die. He even lets her marry his son,** which doesn't make any sense. He is an ambitious man, and Laria has nothing to offer.

A woman is reincarnated into the world of a novel she'd previously read. The character she reincarnates as is Laria Rose Rostree, the terminally-ill, recently-orphaned daughter of a count and countess.

The widowed Duke of Icard (whose late wife was close to her late mother) makes her an offer: if she marries his young son, Evan, he'll repay all of her parents' debts, and ensure that she'll want for nothing in future.

She agrees, but distrusts his motives, as she knows he's supposed to become the villain of the novel at a future point in time. She also eats berries growing in his garden, which she believes will cure her illness in five years.

Laria has pink hair, while the duke and his son (her fiancé) both have black hair and red eyes.

[image] [image]

Comment: Yes this is it thank you!

Comment: @Merriri - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Tumgir is a [malware/adware site](https://www.tumblr.com/blog/view/gyrrakavian/678429380121378816?source=share) that reposts content scraped from Tumblr. If you can't find the original post, can you use a different summary?

Comment: @Laurel - I'll look for something better to replace it with. The synopsis given on my usual go-to sites isn't very useful in terms of matching this to the OP's description.